# ASP.NET MVC 4 Application showing directory contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I developed an intranet based application with ASP.NET MVC 4. I published the application to my desktop. On moving it to another system (client system), I tried installing SQL Server 2012 but had a certain side-by-side error so I installed SQL Server 2005. I did the following:

- Created appPool for the application with .net 4.0 and integrated pipeline mode
- I changed the parameter of the web config file to reflect the username and password on the new sql server (2005).
- Enabled .net frame work 4.0 following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258938/mvc2-website-hosted-on-iis7-shows-directory-listing-not-the-home-index)
- Populated the database with my SQL Script.
- Added the application in inetmgr.

When I viewed the application I had my directory listing staring at me in the face.

All help would be appreciated as I have done everything possible.

Comment: Did you install this one? http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: sorry i use .net framework 4.0 entity frame work 5.0. Why would I need to install that?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio it will be fine to just running in IIS Express. But If you want to move to real IIS you may need to install that.
By the way the the showing directory contents seem it cannot interpret the mvc. By the way there are two kind of 4.0 one is Classic and ther is Integrated. Try change your app pool to Integrated if this fixed.

Comment: @JasonLou: I have changed my app POOL to integrated mode. I still have same issue.

Comment: I am not sure what version of iis you are using but try this step by step: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Comment: @JasonLou: I use the IIS Version shipped with Windows 7 Ultimate. I have tested the App on my office computer with same configuration. The difference is the application on the office computer has a database backend installed on SQL Server 2012 while same App installed on the client computer has a SQL Server 2005 database. The choice of 2005 was because installation of SQL Server  2012 had an issue. (Side-By-Side not compatible issue) which I couldn't fix.

Comment: According to your description:
1. SQL is different version: I do not think that is a key issue but there may some prerequisites for SQL 2012 may effect. Try ODBC to make sure SQL connected/running.
2. Directory listing is showing: This means the "RouteConfig.cs" is not working in your mvc application, So seem mvc app cannot be interpret to the right page or some other setting take effect of the role for mvc.
3. Your mvc application is published version so it is important of "Bin" with dll,
4. try to install Visual Studio in your client computer if possible then prerequisites may be installed.

Comment: @Jason Lou: Thanks for your response. I will install visual studio on the client computer to see if the prerequisites will install. I will feed you back tomorrow. Let me ask you one question... What prerequisites are you talking about here?

Comment: Here is the list: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8164

in SQL part make sure your SQL 2005 update to SP3.

Comment: @Jason Lou: You were right. I installed visual studio 2012 and all the dependencies got installed with it. I can now view the site. Thanks a bunch!