# Asp.net mvc application doesn't start on iis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am new to asp.net mvc. I have created a web application, it seems, successfully deployed it to my iis server. However, when I try to start my webpage by typing the following URL (http://localhost/MyWebApplication) the browser shows me the contents of my application folder instead of starting the page. When I start the application in the debug mode in the VS, everything works perfectly.

Could someone explain, please, how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds like IIS is configured wrong, probably doesn't have ASP.NET enabled. I suggest you look up some tutorials on setting that up correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC2 Website hosted on IIS7 shows directory listing not the Home/Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258938/mvc2-website-hosted-on-iis7-shows-directory-listing-not-the-home-index)